# window.speechSynthesis.getVoices() returns empty array on macOS safari 15.4

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

The function `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` returns an empty array ([]) on my browser (macOS 12.3.1, Safari 15.4). On the previous versions (Safari 15.3, macOs 12.2) the function returned an array with the available voices (SpeechSynthesisVoice objects) as it is supposed to do. Apart from the upgrade nothing else has changed.

In chrome on the same MacBook the function returns 71 voices.

I use the function in a web-application, however the result can simple be reproduced by entering the command in the console. Does anybody have a clue why I don't get any results anymore?

Regards,
Richard

Comment: I observed this as well.  We need to file a bug with apple.

Comment: This still happening, have you guys come across any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm I had the same issue with Safari 15.4. Seems to have been fixed in Safari 15.5 (in Monterey 12.4)