# speechSynthesis.getVoices() returns an empty array on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, speech-synthesis

The problem in question seems to have been [going for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727048/window-speechsynthesis-getvoices-returns-empty-array-on-macos-safari-15-4).

One way to try and go around this is to use hard-coded voice objects as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28993579/3781000). However, it is unclear to me how to use an object like:
`{ name: "Samantha (Enhanced)", voiceURI: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Samantha-premium", lang: "en-US", localService: true, "default": true }`

to instantiate a `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object.

Has anyone come across a way to instantiate a `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object as a workaround for an empty array of available voices? Thanks!